# My <ul></ul> Doesn't Align Correctly With My H3 (Codepen Code Included)

Tags: html, css

I've looked at it all over the place but I can't seem to figure out the error in my code...it's like as if there's a `text-align: right` by default on my ul.

my code snippet:

```css
footer {
  background-color: #444444;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.info {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50%;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}
.info div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 33%;
  vertical-align: top;
  color: white;
}
footer div ul {
  padding-top: 20px;
}
footer div ul li {
  line-height: 1.7em;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  list-style-type: none;
}
footer div h3 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  opacity: 0.9;
}
footer input {
  display: block;
}
.underline {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  /*margin:auto;*/
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <section class="info">
    <article>
      <div>
        <h3>About</h3>
        <div class="underline"></div>
        <ul>
          <li>Contact</li>
          <li>Features</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h3>Explore</h3>
        <div class="underline"></div>
        <ul>
          <li>Designers</li>
          <li>Journal</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h3>Connect</h3>
        <div class="underline"></div>
        <input type="text">
      </div>
    </article>
    
    <article class="end">
    </article>
  </section>
</footer>
```

Here is the link to my codepen code:

https://codepen.io/teenicarus/pen/Ngabex

I appreciate all responses!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `padding-left: 0;` to the `ul` CSS (the `footer div ul` rule) to remove the default left padding.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bRoBPp